# Find closest value to determined multiplicated value

Tags: java

I have two values. One is static and equals 24

```
int A = 24;
```

and I have entries list :

```
[0, 21, 45, 76, 98]
```

All of occurences comes in loop and I want to get closest value which divides on A :

```
0 - 24
21 - 24
45 - 48
76 - 72
98 - 96
```

How to calculate this?

Comment: Integer division followed by multiplication?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth If I use `B % 24` it just return the integer part of value. In case of `45 % 24` it will be **1** instead of **2**

Comment: There's a small tweak you can make to deal with that :)

Answer (score 1):

Using java8 you can stream the array or list and map that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 24;
    List<Integer> mL = Arrays.asList(0, 21, 45, 76, 98);
    Map<Integer, Integer> m = mL.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Integer::intValue, x -> {
        int r = a * (int) Math.round(x / (double) a);
        return r == 0 ? a : r;
    }));
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

the output will be a map where the key is the values to analyse and the values are the closest delta to it

```
{0=24, 98=96, 21=24, 76=72, 45=48}
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to work for all input values, given the constraints of floating-point arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

You could divide each value by `a` **using floating point division**, round it to the closest `int` and then multiply it back again by `a`:

```
int a = 24;
int[] values = new int[]{0, 21, 45, 76, 98};

int[] result =
    Arrays.stream(values).map(v -> a * (int) Math.round(v / (double) a)).toArray();
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to work for all input values, given the constraints of floating-point arithmetic?

Comment: Will integer division do the same thing?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I guess that in theory you could synthesize a case where the result of the division is very close to `n.5`, and the arithmetic error nudges it from one side to another, but I can't think of an actual example to that effect.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no - integer division will truncate the result making the rounding pointless.

Comment: @Mureinik - FWIW, I ran a check for all possible values of `v` (with `a = 24`), and they all gave the right answer.  So I guess this solution **is** correct for at least the OP's particular case :)  I don't know how to prove/disprove it in the general case, though.

Answer (score 0):

To find the largest multiple `x` of a number `n` which is less than a given number `a`, you can use some arithmetic:

```
int x = n - n % a;
```

Now if you want to get the nearest multiple, whether larger or smaller than `a`, you can use an if statement:

```
if (a - x > (x + n) - a)
    x = x + a
```

For a list of numbers, just loop over them or use the Stream API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the arrays are also integers, the correct approach for rounding an integer `a` to the nearest multiple of integer `n` is as follows:<sup>1</sup>

```
(a + n/2) / n * n
```

#### How this works

Hopefully the `a / n * n` approach should be familiar as an approach to get `floor`-like behaviour, due to the way integer maths works.  The `n/2` is a bias to give you `round`-like behaviour instead.<sup>2</sup>

#### Things to be aware of

- Exact ties are rounded *upward*.
- Inputs within `n / 2` of the maximum representable value will cause this to fail.

#### Comparison with other answers

- The floating-point approaches aren't guaranteed to give the right answer for all input values, due to the limitations of floating-point arithmetic. 
  Using `double` *may* work if the inputs are `int`s (although I'm not sure what the proof is).  But it certainly won't be sufficient for `long`s.
- This integer approach may be equivalent to [@CodeApprentice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660250/129570), I'm not sure.  But this approach avoids the conditional.

---

<sub>1. The boilerplate stream/loop code to get this to work for multiple input values is left as an exercise for the reader.</sub>

<sub>2. And for completeness, if you use a bias of `n-1`, you get `ceil`-like behaviour!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to take the remainder and see if you need to add or substract from the given number to get closest number that divides. If remainder is less then half of `A` then substract remainder from the number otherwise add to it the difference between remainder and `A`. Also as a quick exit check if number is less then `A` the closest one is `A` itself.

```
public static int[] closest(int a, int[] b){
        int[] result = new int[ b.length ];

        int halfOfA = a/2;

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
            if ( b[i] <= a ){
                result[i] = a;
            }else{
                int rem =  b[i] % a;                                
                if (rem < halfOfA) result[i] = b[i] - rem;
                else result[i] = b[i] + (a - rem);
            }            
        }        
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this :

- iterate until your are as near as possible of the value (when distance is less than `A/2`

```
private static int closestTo(int a, int i) {
    int res = a;
    while (Math.abs(res - i) > (a / 2.0) && res< i + a) {
        res += a;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And use like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A = 24;
    int[] tab = new int[]{0, 21, 45, 76, 98};
    for (int i : tab) {
        System.out.println(i + " - " + closestTo(A, i));
    }
}
```